# Linq Select causes InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq

```
var courses = db.Courses.Select(course => new Model.Course() {
    Dates = db.Dates
        .Where(date => date.CourseID == course.ID)
        .Select(date => date._Date.ToString())
        .ToList()
});

return courses.ToList();
```

The return call causes **`System.InvalidCastException`**. If I remove Dates, there is no error.

Here's Course class:

```
public class Course {
    public List<string> Dates { get; set; }
}
```

Screenshot from VS:

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `Dates` in your Course Model?

Comment: Does the message specify what you're trying to cast *from* or *to*?

Comment: Is this using Entity Framework? Is role a member of one of the entities?

Comment: I included more relevant data in my question. I have no idea what is meant by 'role'.

Comment: How is the `Course` class mapped to the underlying table? It looks like you're trying to map a string column as an int.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue, you can't map a `List<string>` to a database column. What flavor of LINQ is this? Linq-to-Sql?

Comment: @GertArnold, The code is not mapping a `List<string>` to a database column. Rather, it is assigning it a `List` of whatever type `_Date` column is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.ToString()` on your `_Date` column could be causing the InvalidCastException. Linq to SQL is trying to convert your `_Date` into a string using ToString() which does not exist in SQL. You will need to simply grab the date as is from SQL and convert to string in memory.

Try this:

```
// Grab from db list of courses and their dates. 
// Put dates in a List of DateTime, but you can also use DateTime2.
// Note that courses will be an IQueryable.
var courses = db.Courses.Select(course => new List<DateTime> {
    Dates = db.Dates
        .Where(date => date.CourseID == course.ID)
        .Select(date => date._Date).ToList()
});

// Extract data from SQL by calling our IQueryable's ToList() of method. This puts the data as a List in memory.
// Using the List.Select() method, convert dates to strings. This will return an IEnumerable.
// Convert the resulting IEnumerable back to a List.
return courses
          .ToList()
          .Select(course => new Model.Course
          {
             // Here, you are using the .NET Framework's DateTime.ToString()
             // So you can use any formatting options available with that.
             Dates = course.Dates.Select(date => date.ToString()).ToList()
          })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent! Had to add `.ToList()` to the two inner `.Select()` but it works perfectly.

Comment: Ah yes, because you have a `List` instead of `IEnumerable`. Sorry my mistake. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the complete model but I think you should rather be joining those two tables with a `join` and not a `where` similar to this:

```
var courses = 
    db.Courses
    .Join(
        db.Dates, 
        c => c.ID, 
        d => d.CourseID, 
        (c, d) => new 
        { 
            Course = c, 
            Dates = d 
        }
    ).ToList();
```